Terminal color completion for ip command
I have 2 computers: home and work. Their both OS is ubuntu 22.04.05, but the home one has been installed about 2 weeks ago. Also I use my custom bashrc, inputrc and profile files, here they are:
.bashrc
GREEN="\e[92m"
RESET_COLOR="\e[0m"

git_branch()
{
    BRANCH=$(git branch 2>/dev/null | grep '^*'  | sed 's/* //')

    if [ -z "$BRANCH" ]; then
        echo ""
    else
        echo " $BRANCH"
    fi
}

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
#HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
    if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
        . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
    elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
        . /etc/bash_completion
    fi
fi


alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias ip='ip -c'
alias reboot='sudo reboot'
alias poweroff='sudo poweroff'
alias tree='tree -C'

PS1='[\[\e[34m\]\$\[\e[0m\]\[\e[1;93m\]\w\[\e[0m\]]\[\e[32m\]$(git_branch)\[\e[0m\]: '

if [ -e /usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm-256color ]; then
    export TERM='xterm-256color'
else
    export TERM='xterm-color'
fi

export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

.inpurc
# do not bell on tab-completion
#set bell-style none

set meta-flag on
set input-meta on
set convert-meta off
set output-meta on

set completion-ignore-case on

$if mode=emacs

# for linux console and RH/Debian xterm
"\e[1~": beginning-of-line
"\e[4~": end-of-line
"\e[5~": beginning-of-history
"\e[6~": end-of-history
"\e[7~": beginning-of-line
"\e[3~": delete-char
"\e[2~": quoted-insert
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\e[5D": backward-word
"\e\e[C": forward-word
"\e\e[D": backward-word
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word

# for rxvt
"\e[8~": end-of-line

# for non RH/Debian xterm, can't hurt for RH/DEbian xterm
"\eOH": beginning-of-line
"\eOF": end-of-line

# for freebsd console
"\e[H": beginning-of-line
"\e[F": end-of-line
$endif

#set enable-keypad on

.profile
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi

But there is a problem with autocompletion on my home system. When I type a command ip ... and tab, interfaces have prefix ^[[36m. Example:
[$~]: ip link set 
^[[36menp2s0  ^[[36mlo      ^[[36mwlp3s0 

This problem doesn't appear on my work computer.
Also I checked locale, ${TERM}, ${LS_COLORS}, env vars, bash-completion version and even exported settings from work computer's gnome terminal to my home one, everything are the same, this didn't help to solve this strange behavior.
What can cause this problem and how to get rid of this prefix?

It looks like the completion code for ip uses a shell function _available_interfaces that first tries ifconfig and then falls through to ip link show. So my guess is that one machine has the ifconfig command (from the somewhat deprecated net-tools package) while the other has only ip - and you've aliased that to ip -c which is hence injecting the color sequences into COMPREPLY (not sure why your terminal is interpreting them as such however).

You are right. I remove net-tools from "correct" machine and got the same behavior. Also found an issue with the same problem. After reading code and comments in the issue I found that the devs removes ifconfig util in main branch, not even in the last release tags, so the best solution now - install net-tools. Thanks for help, @steeldriver
